# TypeScript cannot Find name Weakmap

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using typescript 1.6 in my VS, when I try to use WeakMap, I see that Typescript doesn't recognize the name WeakMap.

```
var _mdSideNav: typeof WeakMap;
```

Can any one Suggest any workarounds or solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

You should specify `ECMAScript` version `ECMAScript 6` in TypeScript build settings to use the `WeakMap` type and other `ES6` features.

Answer (score -2):

Seems Like TypeScript Doesn't support WeakMap ( may be I am wrong ). And also, we are not really extending any sealed object, so I am not going to use it.